# Total C++ Noob: File I/O Problems with Boost and std

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, io, std

I am trying to work on a summer simulation project but I can't seem to get the File I/O off the ground. Here is my code:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream F;

int M = 0;    // Model Parameter //

if (F.open (fname)) // Error 1
    std::cout << "Parsing File...";

else {
    std::cout << "***Parsing - ERROR!***" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Invalid filename passed to Parsing::ReadData" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fname = " << fname << " : Can't open file!" << std::endl;
    throw 2;
}

std::getline (F, line);

std::vector<std::string> *result;
boost::split(result, line, boost::is_any_of(":")); // Errors 2 and 3

// Read Number of Metabolites
M = std::atoi(result[1]);  // Error 4

std::cout << "M = " << M << std::endl;

F.close();
```

So far, from what I've read online this seems pretty straightforward to me. Let me know if I should provide any clarification. I'm getting all these errors when I compile and execute:

```
In file included from test_parsing.cpp:11:
./Parsing_Engine.h:72:6: error: value of type 'void' is not contextually
      convertible to 'bool'
        if (F.open (fname))
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Parsing_Engine.h:85:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boost'
        boost::split(result, line, boost::is_any_of(":"));
        ^
./Parsing_Engine.h:85:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boost'
        boost::split(result, line, boost::is_any_of(":"));
                                   ^
./Parsing_Engine.h:88:22: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'
        M = std::atoi(result[1]);
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:216:28: note: 
      template is declared here
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector;
```

For the F.open error, I don't understand why void is not being interpreted as false. For the Boost errors, I don't understand why this is happening because I installed the library using brew. I don't understand what is meant by the implicit instantiation of result, although I assume this error would go away if I could get boost to work.

Any tips for what I'm doing wrong? Also, sorry - I am not sure if this is TMI for a stackoverflow post.

Comment: `std::ifstream::open` does not return anything, are you sure you didn't mean `std::ifstream::is_open`? The latter returns `true` if a file is open and associated with a stream object. You can also check the stream's error flags via `std::ios::good`.

Comment: I think that's definitely what I meant. I assumed that C++'s .open() would work like C's fopen, which would've returned a FILE pointer or NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of [std::basic_fstream<CharT,Traits>::open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) is `void`. You can't use it as a condition. `false` and `true` are values of type `bool`. You can't convert `void` to `bool`.

You can rewrite these lines as

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream F(fname);

if (F)
    std::cout << "Parsing File...";
else {
    std::cout << "***Parsing - ERROR!***" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Invalid filename passed to Parsing::ReadData" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fname = " << fname << " : Can't open file!" << std::endl;
    throw 2;
}
```

Errors 2 and 3 could be caused by missing include directives. You have to include the boost headers.

`result` is a pointer to a vector of strings. `result[1]` is equivalent to `*(result + 1)` and its type is vector of strings. `std::atoi` expects a C string as only parameter. Probably you want

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
boost::split(result, line, boost::is_any_of(":"));

// Read Number of Metabolites
M = std::stoi(result[1]);
```

`std::stoi` takes a `std::string` and converts it to `int`.